# Excel Macro to add new row

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I have a project that i am working on that i need help with some vba magic.

Ultimately what i want the code to do for me is that if a certain value in a range equals a specific string or number, lets say for example "Bananas" then add a new row below that, not a blank one but with specific values and then split the total $ of the original row 50% and add it the new row and go back adjust the original row to now show 50% and not the total amount which it was showing at first.

Sorry for my English, is not really good. Please see image below.

[image]

So now below that row i would want to add another new row saying

```
Name : Store B 
Delivery Date : Same 
Memo : Same
Invoice Number : Same 
Total : 50% of total of Store A row
```

Also after the total is added, i would want to formula to adjust the total for the original Store A row as well.

This is the macro that i was able to build so far. I can get it to add a blank row if A1 equals "Store A" but i cant get it to add all the other requirements.

Macro :

```
Sub BlankLine()
    'Updateby20150203
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "Add New Row"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)
    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
        If Rng.Value = "Store A" Then
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide!

Comment: How is the name field of the new row determined?  Will it always be `Store B` when the row above is `Store A` or is there some process to determine the store name?

Comment: It will always be "Store B" when the row above is "Store A".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use variables to define each peice of information you need and then assign it to the new row like this (I have to apologize, my browser isn't showing the image you posted, so the column references are likely wrong.  You can easily change them to match you worksheet though.):

```
Sub BlankLine()
    'Updateby20150203
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim dt As String
    Dim memo As String
    Dim invoice As String
    Dim total As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "Add New Row"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)
    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
        If Rng.Value = "Store A" Then
                dt = Range("B" & xRowIndex).Value
                invoice = Range("D" & xRowIndex).Value
                memo = Range("E" & xRowIndex).Value
                total = (Range("F" & xRowIndex).Value) / 2
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Range("A" & xRowIndex + 1) = "Store B"
                Range("B" & xRowIndex + 1) = dt
                Range("C" & xRowIndex + 1) = invoice
                Range("D" & xRowIndex + 1) = memo
                Range("E" & xRowIndex + 1) = total
                Range("E" & xRowIndex) = total
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You for the help. It's not working like i want it to but i'll hopefully be able to make some changes to the macro that you send me. Thank You sir! very helpful.